# search a similar isotope gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

Where can I find a  free for comercial use, similar isotope gallery ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not meet the site's guidelines and will likely be closed. StackOverflow is for asking programming related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never actually used it but [Tiles Gallery](http://tiles-gallery.com/) looks like a nice alternative

Comment: Thank's,  but it is not a similar to Isotope Gallery